# npm image gets broken when built built on gitlab-ci

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I build my image locally it works fine:

```
FROM registry.dev.***/mpk/internal/node:20.10
MAINTAINER MPK Software <support@***>
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

COPY . /source/
WORKDIR /source
```

where `registry.dev.***/mpk/internal/node:20.10` equals to `node:20.10` just pushed to the local repository.

```
$ docker run -it d482e4615080 /bin/bash
root@327d92dc8b58:/source# npm start

> start
> live-server --port=4200 --host=0.0.0.0

Serving "/source" at http://127.0.0.1:4200
```

However, when the same image is being built on Gitlab-CI then pulled to another machine the npm installation seems broken:

```
$ docker run -it registry.dev.***/lighthouse/lh-front/lh-front:ci-deploy /bin/bash
root@365c5212e016:/source# npm start

> start
> live-server --port=4200 --host=0.0.0.0

sh: 1: live-server: not found

root@365c5212e016:/source# npm ls
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! missing: concurrently@^6.4.0, required by lighthouse-front@
npm ERR! missing: live-server@^1.2.1, required by lighthouse-front@
npm ERR! missing: prettier@^2.4.1, required by lighthouse-front@
npm ERR! missing: ws@^8.2.3, required by lighthouse-front@
lighthouse-front@ /source
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY concurrently@^6.4.0
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY live-server@^1.2.1
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY prettier@^2.4.1
`-- UNMET DEPENDENCY ws@^8.2.3
```

This is the build code from `.gitlab-ci.yml` which is pretty much similar to the local build code:

```
  script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - BRANCH_IMG="registry.dev.***/lighthouse/lh-front/lh-front:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
    - docker build --no-cache -f docker/lh-front/Dockerfile -t $BRANCH_IMG . 
    - docker push $BRANCH_IMG
```

Local build code:

`docker build -f docker/lh-front/Dockerfile .`

Comment: Compare the files you have in local vs. what is in Gitlab CI (i.e what is commited to Git). I guess you have stuff in local that are needed (node_modules?).

Comment: Attaching the full CI script. The code equality is being checked continually by `git status`. The image was fixed by adding `npm install` directive. Still it feels curious to know why it worked in 2 different ways WITHOUT it.

Comment: Because you had run `npm install` on your laptop yourself before. And because you're copying `.` which is "all files". If you were copying only specific files (sources), issue would be the same in local.